# Qual é a diferença entre o novo operador JOIN e os anteriores?

Tags: sql, join

Estava vendo alguns exemplos de SQL em Oracle, e notei que é possível fazer apenas `JOIN`.

#### Exemplo

```
SELECT
    T1.*,
    T2.desc
FROM
    table1 T1
    JOIN table2 T2 ON T2.id = T1.id_table2
```

#### Pergunta

- Qual a diferença desse operador?
- Qual a relação com `LEFT`, `RIGHT`? Ou ele é o mesmo que um `FULL`?

#### Adendo

Pergunta relacionada : [Qual é a diferença entre INNER JOIN e OUTER JOIN?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/6441/14213)

Comment: O `JOIN` é apenas uma abreviação do `INNER JOIN`

Comment: Nada de errado com sua pergunta, só uma observação: _Novo operador JOIN?_ Que eu saiba o `JOIN` sem complemento não é assim tão novo, ja existe a um b**oooo**m tempo :P

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Qual a diferença desse operador?

Nenhuma. `JOIN` é exatamente a mesma coisa que `INNER JOIN`. É apenas [*syntax sugar*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%C3%A7%C3%BAcar_sint%C3%A1tico).

Na própria [documentação do *inner join*](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.6.2.1/ref/rrefsqlj35034.html#rrefsqlj35034) da Oracle, é possível ver que a palavra *inner*  está entre colchetes, indicando que ela é opcional.

> **Syntax**
>
> ```
> TableExpression [ INNER ] JOIN TableExpression  
> {  
>     ON booleanExpression |  
>     USING clause  
> }
> ```

> Qual a relação com LEFT, RIGHT? Ou ele é o mesmo que um FULL?

Nenhuma relação com `LEFT` ou `RIGHT JOIN`, tampouco com `FULL/OUTER JOIN`.